# Recrear las migraciones

Tags: laravel, migration

Tengo un proyecto en Laravel que uso para pruebas y aprendizaje. Se me han borrado los ficheros de migraciones, aunque tengo la base de datos. Me gustaría saber si en Laravel 5.8 hay posibilidades de que recree las migraciones a partir de la estructura de la base de datos. Tengo también la tabla donde se almacenan las migraciones. Lo único que me falta es el código de las mismas. ¿Se puede hacer?

Comment: Lo siento, no me parece possible recrear una exacta secuencia de migraciones que tuviste porque no hay datos históricos de estructura de la base de datos. Pero puedes generar una nueva migracion grande que va a hacer todo https://www.5balloons.info/create-migration-files-from-existing-database-in-laravel/

Comment: Hay algunos paquetes con los que puedes generar las migraciones a partir de la base de datos. Pero a parte de esto, mi recomendación pasa por que empieces a utilizar git y evitar que esto te vuelva a pasar en un futuro.